# Cypress opposite of contains

Tags: javascript, cypress, contains

I code in cypress.
Exists something like opposite of cy.contains()? Something like cy.notContains().

I tried:

```
cy.get('table').should(($table) =>{
            expect($table).to.not.contain("Hello world")
        })
```

But it does not work. Event if the text wasn't in the table, cypress didn't show any error.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do \`cy.notContains(text)\` in cypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70841070/how-to-do-cy-notcontainstext-in-cypress)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

just like this -

```
cy.get('table').not('Hello World')
```

[Reference](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/not)